# Changing constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uistoryboard

I am creating an app with quite a lot of buttons. I have already placed all required buttons on the view and all constraints are set. Everything is done in the storyboard.

I want to create a button which will change all buttons layout. In order to do that I will need to change all buttons constraints.

So, for example, after clicking "change button layout" all buttons will change their position on the view like x coordinate by +20 and y coordinate by +20.

Is there an easy way to do this? or I need to change all constraints programmatically in code if "change button layout" button is clicked?

Thanks

Comment: are your constraint for button dependent on each other.?

Comment: No, they don't. They are aligned to center x and y and multipliers are given to each button to place each button to the right position.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options:

1. As previously suggested, create a container to which you will add all the buttons programmatically or through storyboard and then manipulate the container which will auto manipulate all of it's children.
2. You could create all the buttons programmatically, this would probably be the correct approach. You would keep them all in some sort of array or list and then manipulate their properties in for/foreach/any other loop.
3. I am not entirely sure if you can get all the items from a storyboard by some sort of a type getter, in case you really want all the buttons created on storyboard. With this getter you could fill an aforementioned array and manipulate it the same way through loops.

The best way to do this is probably simply creating a container and putting all the buttons inside it and then manipulating the container.

Comment: you can always access a specific child inside a container if you need to move only that one.
Are you missing a part of the comment there?

Comment: By container do You mean a new view where all buttons will be located or something like IBCollection?

Comment: It depends on the approach you take in making this. It's either a new view that would wrap all the children(buttons) or if you want to do this programmatically, it would be a collection of some sort, any you prefer, which would still have to be transformed into the view+children format to be added to the interface. You should elaborate a little bit more on what you want to achieve. A use-case would help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a container for all the buttons, and manage the container’s constraints.

Comment: I would really appreciate if could post a sample code of how it can be done. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As antonsergeev88 suggested you should create a container and manage its constraints. But if you want to move every button by a specific value you could use CGAffineTransform.

**SWIFT**

```
myButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 20, y: 20)
```

**OBJECTIVE C**

```
myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(20, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to create Buttons Programmatically
Objective -C
//Program**

self.button = [UIbutton buttonWithtype:UIbuttonTypeCustom];

self.button.frame = cgrectMake(x-axis value,y-axis value,width,height);

**//cgrect(0,50,100,100) creates button at (0,50) with with Width 100 and Height 100..**

self.button setTitle:@"Button One" forState:UIControlStateNormal;
[self.view addsubView:self.button];